# AWS DMS Migration task Source MongoDB and Target RDS Postgres

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, replicaset, aws-dms

From few week all DMS tasks were successfully running,
recently I restarted one table by adding few more columns
but now after full loads is completed and ongoing replication starts after few seconds this
even when I start that table loading from stratch.

error comes:

`Replication task has failed. Reason: Last Error Error reading the database log. Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2880] [1020460] Error executing source loop; Stream component failed at subtask 0, component st_0_YF7WZ2RCSVJ5YSNKTAJBYWAUWT3T7WKW4CXV6BA; Stream component 'st_0_YF7WZ2RCSVJ5YSNKTAJBYWAUWT3T7WKW4CXV6BA' terminated [reptask/replicationtask.c:2888] [1020460] Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL.`

Error in Cloud watch logs

````
[SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]E:  Expected to read 4 operations as part of transaction '
{
    "lsid": {
        "id": {
            "$binary": {
                "base64": "Gn5w6RP****sSG1w==",
                "subType": "04"
            }
        },
        "uid": {
            "$binary": {
                "base64": "c5zE0wpKRhgcs6YLEzR******LVUqMjMseoKo=",
                "subType": "00"
            }
        }
    },
    "txnNumber": {
        "$numberLong": "1"
    }
}
' but read 2 [1020460]  (change_streams_capture.c:894)
2022-07-10T12:31:24 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Expected to read 4 operations as part of transaction '{ "lsid" : { "id" : { "$binary" : { "base64": "Gn5w6DMW*****PsSG1w==", "subType" : "04" } }, "uid" : { "$binary" : { "base64": "c5zE0wpKRhgcs6****8Gynk4RLVUqMjMseoKo=", "subType" : "00" } } }, "txnNumber" : { "$numberLong" : "1"} }' but read 2 [1020460] (change_streams_capture.c:894)
[SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]I:  Destroying mongoc client: '22360472577088'  (mongodb_imp.c:1161
Destroying mongoc oplog client: '22360472609024'  (mongodb_imp.c:1168)
[SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]E:  Error executing source loop [1020460]  (streamcomponent.c:1872)```
````